# Problema con contador Pascal

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Necesito ayuda con un proyecto de Pascal. Se crea un programa que es un juego, se genera un texto aleatorio de 4 letras y el usuario tiene que intentar adivinarlas.

Tiene que salir un contador de las letras que acierta en la misma posición *(eso lo tengo ok)*, y de las letras que acierta, pero están en otra posición a las del aleatorio.

¿Me podéis ayudar por favor?

Adjunto parte del código.

```
{REPETICION MAXIMO INTENTOS}  
    repeat
    it2:=it2+1;
    write('Intento ',it2,' de ',MAX_INTENTOS,'>> ');

    {RECORRIDO DE LOS ARRAYS}
    for it1:= 1 to LARGO_CODIGO do begin
      read(arrayCodigoUsuario[it1]);

        {CONDICIÓN PARA CONTADOR DE B}
        bOk:=arrayCodigoUsuario[it1]=arrayCodigoSecreto[it1];
        if bOk=true then begin
        contadorB:=contadorB+1;
        end;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ayudarte con que?

Comment: El código que publicas es insuficiente para poder ver dónde está tu problema. Te sugiero preparar un [mcve]. Hago énfasis en que sea _completo_. Un saludo.

Comment: Es posible que la solución esté en usar un segundo bucle, pero coincido con otros compañeros en que falta parte de tu código. Por lo tanto no se si después de este bucle FOR estás ejecutando otro. Antes de comentar posibles alternativas coloca el código completo, de otra forma es posible que las sugerencias que te hagamos sean incorrectas o te confundan en lugar de aclararte las cosas.